# mapping SQLquery to plain Object, not Entity

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, mapping

I have following **Java method**:

```
public void loadData()
{
  session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  String sql = "select s.column1, SUM(s.column2), 'hi' as column3 from Source s group by s.column1";
  Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Test.class);
  dataList = query.list();
}
```

**Class Source**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SourceTable")
public class Source implements Serializable 
{
  @Id
  private int column1;
  private int column2;
  + getters and setters
}
```

Appropriate **class Test**:

```
@Entity  // why?
public class Test implements Serializable 
{
  @Id
  private int column1;
  private int column2;
  private String column3;
  + getters and setters
}
```

And **hibernate mapping**:

```
...
<mapping class="objects.Test"/> // why?
<mapping class="tables.Source"/>
...
```

**Everything is working fine**, but i don't understand one thing:

Why the object `Test` has to be mapped in `hibernate.xml` and signed by `@Entity` tag, if it has no reflection in real SQL server? Why it couldn't be a 'plain' Java object?

When I delete `@Entity` and `<mapping class="objects.Test"/>` it reports following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: objects.Test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be, but you've explicitly marked it as entity by using it as a result of what hibernate is calling the [entity query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e3709)

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Test.class);
```

what you should do instead is [return a non-managed entity in a query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e3832) so write something like

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Test.class));
```

In the later case, your *Test* class should be a plain POJO with the properties matching the select columns

Comment: Thank you, but i've got a following report now: `org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -15`

Comment: it means that the underlying type cannot be mapped to a Java type, you can use scalar method, or add the mapping by using a custom dialect, read more here http://www.luyue.org/fix-hibernate-dialect-mapping-jdbc-type/

Comment: np, hope it will help you

Comment: `cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method addEntity`